# what can be the reasons for backspace not working in php?

Tags: php, backspace

```
<?php
echo "hello\x08";
?>
```

the out put to this is coming as

hello

I am working on xampp as localhost

```
$reply='{';
        while($row=$this->conx->fetch_array($result)){
            $user=new user();
            $fullname=$user->get('fullname','id',$row['posted_by']);
            $now=getdat($row['posted_on']);
            $reply.='"count'.$count.'":{"id":'.$row['post_id'].',"user":"'.$fullname['fullname'].'","msg":"'.$row['msg'].'","at":"'.$now.'"},';
        }
        $reply.='}';
    return $reply;}
```

How can I remove the last ',' from reply?

Comment: Does your output (CLI or web browser) handle backspace as a display character?

Comment: It works on the console (if there was a space after the BS), but not in webpages.

Comment: It's not "working" because backspace has no special meaning when interpreted as text -- either plain or inside HTML.

Comment: Refer to this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440011/php-backspace-character-during-output-possible

Comment: I am not getting you @Mark Baker

Comment: you need to remove the last char from your string `substr($str, 0, strlen($str) -  1)` i hope that function names are right

Comment: @vishu HTML or Windows CLI doesn't recognise a displayed x08 character as a backspace... in the CLI, it simply moves the cursor back one character. Try `echo "hello\x08" . "boy";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try.

```
  $reply = rtrim($reply,",");
```

Using your example

```
$reply='{';
        while($row=$this->conx->fetch_array($result)){
            $user=new user();
            $fullname=$user->get('fullname','id',$row['posted_by']);
            $now=getdat($row['posted_on']);
            $reply.='"count'.$count.'":{"id":'.$row['post_id'].',"user":"'.$fullname['fullname'].'","msg":"'.$row['msg'].'","at":"'.$now.'"},';
        }
        $reply.='}';
    return rtrim($reply,",");}
```

Comment: Great glad to help, feel free to upvote and accept the answer. :)